# How do I find the largest 10 files in a given directory?

Tags: perl, bash, filesize

How do I find the largest 10 files in a given directory, with Perl or Bash?

EDIT:

- I need this to be recursive.
- I only want to see large files, no large directories.
- I need this to work on Mac OS X 10.6 ('s version of find).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This prints the 10 largest files recursively from current directory.

```
find . -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -nr | awk '{print $2}' | head -10
```

Comment: How to also print out their sizes to verify the result are correct?

Comment: `$ find . -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -nr | head -10` works.

Comment: Actually this doesn't work on Mac OS X. It doesn't have a printf option.

Comment: @user001 without using `-printf` option, you can try this: `find .  -type f -ls  | awk '{print $7" "$11}' | sort -nr | head -10`

Comment: `find . -type f -ls | awk '{print $7" "$11}' | sort -nr | head -10` prints nothing.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ alias ducks
alias ducks='du -cs * |sort -rn |head -11'
```

Comment: Doesn't this output include subdirectories?

Answer (score 5):

This is a way to do it in perl. (Note: Non-recursive version, according to earlier version of the question)

```
perl -wE 'say for ((sort { -s $b <=> -s $a } </given/dir/*>)[0..9]);'
```

However, I'm sure there are better tools for the job.

**ETA:** Recursive version, using [**File::Find**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind):

```
perl -MFile::Find -wE '
    sub wanted { -f && push @files, $File::Find::name }; 
    find(\&wanted, "/given/dir"); 
    @files = sort { -s $b <=> -s $a } @files; 
    say for @files[0..9];'
```

To check file sizes, use e.g. `printf("%-10s : %s\n", -s, $_) for @files[0..9];` instead.

Comment: Tanks for giving the Perl solution. I am wondering if this has significantly different memory footprint from the solution using `find`?

Comment: @user001 I don't know how `find` works internally, so I cannot say. It may also vary depending on your file system and number of files. You'd need to try it out and see.

Answer (score 0):

How about this -

```
find . -type f -exec ls -l {} + | awk '{print $5,$NF}' | sort -nr | head -n 10
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] find . -type f -exec ls -l {} + | awk '{print $5,$NF}' | sort -nr | head -n 10
8887 ./backup/GTP/GTP_Parser.sh
8879 ./backup/Backup/GTP_Parser.sh
6791 ./backup/Delete_HIST_US.sh
6785 ./backup/Delete_NORM_US.sh
6725 ./backup/Delete_HIST_NET.sh
6711 ./backup/Delete_NORM_NET.sh
5339 ./backup/GTP/gtpparser.sh
5055 ./backup/GTP/gtpparser3.sh
4830 ./backup/GTP/gtpparser2.sh
3955 ./backup/GTP/temp1.file
```

Comment: This is not a solution to what I asked. It outputs a bunch of directories.

Comment: @user001 I have added sample output from the one-liner tested on Mac OSX Lion

Comment: Thanks, it works correctly.  I ran it in a wrong directory where there were no file.

Comment: @user001 :) No worries. I was a little skeptical of the accepted answer since it used `find's printf` option which isn't available in `mac`.

Comment: Don't use `{}` in shell part to avoid [shell injection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/12574)

Answer (score 0):

With recent `find` (2023) and `bash`:

I use `GNU findutils 4.9.0`

```
shopt -s nullglob

print0 () { 
    [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\0' "$@"
}
readarray -td '' files < <(
    print0 * |
    find -files0-from - -type f -printf '%b\t%p\0' |
    sort -rzn |
    cut -zf2 -
) 
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]:0:10}"
```

- **this allow all types of files** (newlines, spaces, special characters...)
- `${files[@]:0:10}` is taking **files** array element from key 0 to 10